# open cart extension mysql_query error after updating open cart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have one opencart extension work in old version, as now I update open cart to new version this stop working. Can any one help me how to fix that?

```
$table = DB_PREFIX . $table;
            
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");

if ($result) {
                    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $field_array[] = $row['Field'];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!in_array($field, $field_array)){
                    $query = 'ALTER TABLE ' . $table . ' ADD ' . $field . ' ' . $def;
                    if ($after != NULL){ $query .= " AFTER " . $after;}
                    $result = $this->db->query($query);
                }
            }
```

The error I am getting is:

> Unknown: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: field_array in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/

I am trying to fix that from last 4 days but can't fix. If I use:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
```

I got error bellow:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /

If I use:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
```

I got error:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->db->query` for running queries in opencart as below:

```
 $result = $this->db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
```

Instead of `mysql_num_rows` use `$result->num_rows`.

Check `Understanding the database object` in [How to become an OpenCart guru?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru) to know more about opencart database object.

Have a nice day !!